# Прикрутить git к processbuilder

Tags: java, git

решил поработать с командной строкой в java. Нашел способ работы с `cmd` через `ProcessBuilder`. Далее я сделал батник, внутри которого: `git status`. Код программы на Java

```
ProcessBuilder ps = new ProcessBuilder();
ps.command("C:\\Users\\practic\\Desktop\\tt\\date.bat");
```

При запуске батника выдает ошибку: `'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`.

После чего я решил вписать в батник: `where git`
Java выдает на это: `INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)`.

Если же прописывать все это в cmd, то все работает

Что можно сделать? чтобы команды гита срабатывали? Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы предложил не мучать `Process` ( и тем более не парсить ответ), а заиспользовать [jGit](https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) библиотеку. 
Посмотреть пример вызова `git status` можно [отсюда](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadle):

```
     try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {
            Status status = git.status().call();
            System.out.println("Added: " + status.getAdded());
            System.out.println("Changed: " + status.getChanged());
            System.out.println("Conflicting: " + status.getConflicting());
            System.out.println("ConflictingStageState: " + status.getConflictingStageState());
            System.out.println("IgnoredNotInIndex: " + status.getIgnoredNotInIndex());
            System.out.println("Missing: " + status.getMissing());
            System.out.println("Modified: " + status.getModified());
            System.out.println("Removed: " + status.getRemoved());
            System.out.println("Untracked: " + status.getUntracked());
            System.out.println("UntrackedFolders: " + status.getUntrackedFolders());
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое